# Is editing a .mui file from a Windows language pack safe?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language-pack

I had the idea to give some Windows 10 UI elements funny names. E.g. renaming the "Shut down" button. With ResourceHacker I think I found the file of the language pack that contains the label for the button: `C:\Windows\System32\en-GB\ShutdownUX.dll.mui`
[view of the file in ResourceHacker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ki9.jpg)

I've never tempered much with system files before so I wanted to ask if anyone knows / can imagine if there is any danger in editing these files with a software like ResourceHacker. It looks like I could just enter some letters there and press save.
I mean it wouldn't be a problem if some buttons showed gibberish but is there any danger of breaking Windows completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not explicitly safe. Corrupted .mui files will cause the associated dll to fail loading. Windows will generally be fine, but whatever relies on those resources may break. In your case, the ShutdownUX resources are used by the start menu and Settings and such, so be aware of how to roll back changes without those if needed.

There are some I would avoid messing with like `explorer.exe.mui` and any signed .mui files. There's a [checksum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-resource-management#features-of-the-mui-resource-technology) to keep in mind too, but looks like it's only calculated from the major and minor version numbers of a file and the file name (case sensitive). As long as you don't corrupt them, mui edits should be fine. Note that Windows updates and diagnostic tools like dism/sfc may replace any that have been changed

That said, it's pretty simple to set up a virtual machine and try it out safely.